# Recovering emails deleted from bin

Tags: finder, mail.app, email

Aware this might be a long shot, but my mother just deleted her entire email inbox. She was attempting to clear her junk box and muscle memory kicked in while she was in the wrong mailbox, and she accidentally selected her entire *Inbox*, deleted it, then went into her bin on autopilot, selected all and emptied that.

Obviously the bin is designed as a failsafe in case someone accidentally deletes an email, but I'm wondering if there's any means of recovery if someone has two accidents in a row and empties something from the bin.

I've tried going to `~/Library/Mail` and scouring the folders found some `.mbox` folders, including `INBOX.mbox` which contains a bunch of obfuscated folders (named only single digit numbers), some of which contain, a couple of levels down, `Attachments` and `Messages` folders, and some of *them* contain `.emlx` and `.partial.emlx` files.

This was encouraging, but opening a few of the ones with more recent modification dates shows they're all a few months old at least, and most of them a year or older, and mainly unimportant stuff like Amazon delivery notices. Obviously it's possible to go through every folder and file individually and see if there's anything important, but I didn't see anything that looked like it could be recent.

I kind of doubt there's a 'front-end' means of undoing the bin-clearing, as it's designed as a final action for most users, but I was wondering if I'm missing some folder somewhere that might contain recently deleted `.emlx` files.

Comment: Any TimeMachine backups?

Comment: If the Bin in Mail has been emptied (Erase Deleted Items...) the messages are gone. What is the state of backup?

Comment: Who is the mail provider? Gmail (and maybe some others) keep an Archive folder.

Comment: No recent Time Machine backups, unfortunately. She uses iCloud (@mac.com domain) and normally checks it through the native Mail app on her iPhone. I checked on iCloud.com to see if there were any automatic backups in the cloud, but couldn't see anything. Looks like it's a closed case, sadly. Hopefully people will contact her about anything important!